How can I get HTTP requests to my local machine?
I have a cheap webhosting server (Google). Users fill out the form and then the form data is emailed to myself. In the form the users send instructions on what to print, and how much to print.
In my house, I have a second computer that uses an IDLE IMAP connection to get alerted to these emails. They are then processed by the custom software on this 2nd computer. I cannot perform the processing on Google's server due to it not being powerful enough, and because I need it to be printed in Australia (not USA).
I just think this is kind of stupid.
I would've thought I could use some kind of HTTP request system but I can't figure it out. I would prefer not to open up my local network directly to the outside world. Is there not some way to stream the requests from Google's server to my home PC without using email? The current setup actually does work, I just feel like there should be a more elegant way than email.

what kind of task are you working on? file size? need more details.

Good point @Raptor, I've added more context. Sorry for that

Websockets and Server-Sent Events seem to solve my needs.
